# Is there an equivalent to the assertive/polite expression "je me permets de ..." in English?

Tags: phrase-requests, translation

Is there an equivalent to the expression "je me permets de ..." in English?

I think this expression has two usages:

- to convey an assertive tone:
  ***Je me permets de** vous rappeler que la date limite est le 19 novembre.*
- to simply ask something politely:
  ***Je me permets de** vous demander si vous pourriez m'aider sur la rédaction de ce contrat.*

---

I would also like to ask if whether a one-to-one translation is possible:

- I **allow myself** to ask a question.
- I would like to **allow myself** to ask a question.

Comment: "May I ..." is idiomatic, polite and can be said assertively.

Comment: @WeatherVane Is it used a lot, or? Is it more in Great Britain or in the US?

Comment: English does have the phrase *take the liberty*, which is close to being a straightforward translation, but its patterns of usage are not quite the same.

Comment: In English, we do say: Allow me to say X, which in French is: Permettez-moi de vous dire. There is no one to one here at all. Tuffy's got it right.

Comment: ***Je me permets de vous rappeler que la date limite est le 19 novembre.*** -> If I may/could/might (in order of assertiveness)  remind you that … -- ***Je me permets de vous demander si vous pourriez m'aider sur la rédaction de ce contrat.*** I hope you don’t mind my asking …

Comment: @Greybeard You should enter an answer with those suggestions, which are also good, like Tuffy's because they get the cultural context of the thing which automated translation cannot grasp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Je me permets de vous rappeler que la date limite est le 19 novembre.

This carries the assertive strength of

If I may/could/might (in order of assertiveness) remind you that …

(I assume the difference in French will be the tone of voice.)

These are classic understatements: the greater the understatement, the greater its force.

The "**may**" is assertive but mild - the implication is that permission is sought, whereas the real implication is that permission is irrelevant.

The "**could**" is assertive - It implies that the reminding is something that, possibly, may not be necessary, whereas the real implication is that the speaker is sure that the listener has forgotten or ignored the criteria and that the reminding is essential.

**Might** is very assertive - the implication is that the speaker is unsure that he has the rank or right to point out a fault, whereas the real implication is that the speaker is furious, he knows he is superior to the listener, and that the listener is an idiot.

> Je me permets de vous demander si vous pourriez m'aider sur la rédaction de ce contrat.

I hope you don’t mind my asking … This is polite and deferential.

Comment: I would like to accept this answer, if the following points are addressed in the answer: Is the "if" mandatory? What about the 1-to-1 translation with "let" and/or "allow"?

Comment: @starckman Of course the if is necessary. That "if" is what makes it a meaning that is culturally equivalent. That's the whole point of it.

Comment: @starckman The direct translation "I permit/allow myself ..." simply does not work. It is not idiomatic in this context.

Answer (score 1):

The French represents a kind of understatement.  It sounds polite, but is really there to convey the speaker's sense of superiority.  The nearest English equivalent is

> I take the liberty of...

The speaker's words are meant to suggest a humility/deference which the speaker does not feel.  And this façon de parler is meant in both languages to humiliate the addressee.

Comment: This is often the case, yes. Except in context: I'm going to take the liberty of saying x

Comment: @Lambie Yes, you are right.  This kind of locution is a way of apologising in advance for the offence I am about to give.

Comment: That's exactly right. I prefer phrase to locution, but never mind, we agree. You know this kind of pragmatic meaning in French (the English, as in Brits, have other ones)  always reminds me of Bon appétit. Can you see why? :)

Comment: @Lambie Yes, calling a phrase a 'locution' in the way I did, has the effect of holding it delicately between the thumb and forefinger as if it were something distasteful.

Comment: Ha ha ha. Yes, quizzically examining the worm.

Answer (score 0):

If we take a typical use of this expression, it appears that there are three main renderings.

- I would like to
- May I
- Let me

*Je me permet de (vous faire remarquer que …)*
[I would like to]/[May I]/[Let me] point out (to you) that …

This can be checked on [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator).

Comment: "Allow me (to)" is similar to "Let me" and also seems to reflect the original meaning nicely.

Comment: Checked on DeepL? These automated translation programs are a curse, really.  And the the entire pragmatic meaning is entirely missed.

Comment: @Lambie I think you exaggerate; those programs are already marvels of precision despite the fact that now and again something goes through the mesh of their scrutinizing systems.

Comment: If that is so, why is every single thing it proposes wrong? And why is it that you can't see that it is wrong? Maybe you are "ignoring it" [French meaning of ignore].

Comment: @Lambie  Now, that is not exaggerating from your part any more, it is plain lying, but I can't see why you do that. No, it is not as you say, I can see that very often  the translations obtained from DeepL are quite good; there is no reason why I should _pretend_ that they are good. If you are hoping to make me revise my judgement, as on so many other things, expecting me to say that white is black, and thereby get some kind of obscure satisfaction, one more time you are going to be disappointed.

Comment: Do as you like, I really don't care. Calling me a liar is a bit heavy. The problem is understanding limitations. Unless you have internalized the cultural pragmatics of Je me permets de [whatver], and understand the equivalent cultural idea in English, il faut mieux plier bagages. ["from your part" is not idiomatic in English, by the way.]

Comment: @Lambie "On your part" is the usual form, but you do find "from": "From now on, I'm not going to accept any insinuation coming from your part. ",
"For the world in general, your behavior is all that you do, just because this is what the world can see and acknowledge from your part, technically.".

Comment: None of that is right in English.  The only thing we say in English like that is: **for my part**. For my, your, his, her, their, our part, are the possibilities. NOT from and NOT on. "your behavior is all that you do"? What does that even mean? You need to listen to me when I'm helping you and not criticize me.

Comment: @Lambie I agree with you on that point: "your behavior is all that you do" is very poor English. Nevertheless, my assertion that "from" is acceptable stands; here are a few more examples from serious sources, and others, still, will be found. (1/2)

Comment: @Lambie ♦ It would then permit them to do that in the morning and it might save a lot of discussion here, **from our part**.
♦ …methodically towards execution of our action and that would ensure better management and performance **from our part**. 
♦ Don't they rather deserve **from our part** an appreciation, for all those Jews, who in spite of passing such a terrible experience, …
♦ of its deep significance and promotive effects for our intellectual and public life , will be published **from our part** after the finishing of the chief actions of relief … (2/2)

Comment: I am afraid that this discussion has got off the rails and is obscuring a very important matter raised by @Lambie's original comment. We may disagree about the merits of particular translation software, and about how how well it works in a particular case, but such software, no matter how good, should **never be treated as an authority**. Translation software can thus never be used to 'check' the judgements of competent human translators; on the contrary it is the judgements of competent human translators that determine how good the software is.

Comment: @jsw29 For my part, I do appreciate your comments. These days, many translation companies out there want proofers for their crap and don't want to pay much for that yet the process involves as much if not more effort than straight translation.

Comment: @jsw29 I agree entirely with your outlook on  translating machines, unconditionnally insofar as what you just stated, and I do not think I said anything that could contradict your opinion.

Comment: They are not machines, they are automatic translation programs or platforms and now you are contradicting what you said above.

Comment: @Lambie What do you think a Turing machine is? Hardware?

Comment: **Machine translation software**: https://weglot.com/blog/machine-translation-software/